# open graph meta tags not working in facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, tags, meta

Okay, I can not figure this out for the life of me. I created a new site, and wanted to add the open graph meta tags like on my old site (which is working fine). When I added these to my new site and tested them in facebook debugger, it says that they are not present. I get this back when I test it:

> Inferred Property The 'og:url' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
>
> Inferred Property  The 'og:title' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
>
> Inferred Property  The 'og:description' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
>
> Inferred Property  The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.

Also, it is not finding the image even though it is there as well. Here is the code from my site as follows:

```
<meta property="fb:admins" content="100002683693547" /> 
<meta property="og:title" content="JDerry Art" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.jderry.com/2015" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.jderry.com/2015/images/link.jpg" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Art and Illustration by J. Derry" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="JDerry Art" />
```

my new site URL is: http://www.jderry.com/2015/
I have tried all suggestions for similar issues on here and other forums, as well as tried moving the order of the tags to no avail...
Any and all help will be greatly appreciated as this is starting to drive me nuts as there appears to be no definite answer and all suggested solutions yield the same problem. Thanks in advance.

P.S. My old site was xhtml and my new site is HTML5, not sure if that has any influence on this issue?

Comment: I went to http://www.jderry.com/2015 and I can't see any og-tags on it.

Comment: check whether you can see them on your chrome developer tools . i can't find any when i checked the source.

Comment: Hi All, I just re-uploaded my site (looks like my FTP client was acting dumb and saying the files were there). I just tried everything again and the problem persists.

Comment: `<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.jderry.com/2015" />` should be `<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.jderry.com/2015/" />` not relevant to current issue, but it should be with **/** at the end

Answer (score 3):

When you are using Open Graph Object Debugger . make sure you check the time last scraped and make sure its up to date with the changes on your website.

[image: facebook graph object debugger]

you can click on **fetch new scrape information** , to get the new data. and right now your open graph tags are working fine .

```
These are the raw tags that we found
Meta Tag    <meta property="fb:admins" content="100002683693547" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:title" content="JDerry Art" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.jderry.com/2015" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.jderry.com/2015/images/link.jpg" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:description" content="Art and Illustration by J. Derry" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:site_name" content="JDerry Art" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, and what was causing it for me was that the content of `og:url` was just `mywebsite.com`, and not `http://www.mywebsite.com`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem for me was that I had ipv6 enabled for my site and I didn't had a proper configuration in my web server settings.

Answer (score 0):

HEY GUYS HERE'S MY ANSWER, i HOPE IT WORKS FOR YOU AS WELL: I try'ed every sugestion I can get my hands on, and what worked for me was this:
go to: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/

Once you are there, paste the URL from the web page you wish to share in the box, and hit the button "retrieve information from the new extraction"

After you do this, it will appear some information, WHAT YOU ARE GOING TO NEED from this information, is the "og:update_time" element, on the right side of this element you will have a number, you are going to need to add this element along with this number to your meta information, someting like this:

meta property="og:updated_time"       content="1496821331"

every number for every page is UNIQUE, but I find that if you put the same number in more than one web page it still works, but you may wanna put the specific number for each web page you are going to need (NOTE: in my experience,
you DONT need to have the image in the same directory as the meta is, actually, I use an image from google images and work out just fine!)
[this is an example of the og:updated_time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYEzK.jpg)

I hope this can help you guys.

Answer (score 0):

How I fixed this issue:

Turns out that the facebook scraper was **timing out** before it could get the content. You can check if this is happening to you with [this tool.](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object) It will give a red error message if it is indeed timing out.

I'm making a wordpress site so I fixed this with the "Super Cache" plugin, which caches the content so that the facebook scraper can load it fast enough to not timeout. You still have to scrape multiple times (up to 4) with the [sharing debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/) for all the content to come through and work because the image loading is asynchronous.