# Meta tags for Open Graph - Facebook can't create thumbnail

Tags: facebook, tags, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

1. These are the meta tags that I use (I hope am using them right). What do you use mostly?
2. Also I have a problem when sharing my website on facebook. the og:image is for forcing facebook to use an image of my preference as a thumbnail. Instead of that facebook is using a wrong image and marked it as "safe_image" (safe_image.php). Why is this happening?

   ```
   <meta property="og:title" content="Myname - Best Products in Town">
   <meta property="og:type" content="Product">
   <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.mybestproducts.com/">
   <meta property="og:site_name" content="Myname">
   <meta property="og:description" content="Selling the best products">
   <meta property="og:image" content="images/mylogo.png">
   <meta property="og:image:width" content="550">
   <meta property="og:image:height" content="550">
   ```

Also I read this one first : [FB OpenGraph og:image not pulling images (possibly https?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8855361/fb-opengraph-ogimage-not-pulling-images-possibly-https)

But since I dont use https I don't think it's my case. So you what you think guys? 
Thank you all in advance

Comment: Do I have to add this: <meta property="fb:admins" content="[FB-USER-ID-NUMBER]"/>  ??  Is it has to do with not grasping images?

Comment: This is the link from the image (when inspecting element) : 

https://fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net/safe_image.php?d=AQB7IVb8_GIR9Kxl&w=158&h=158&url=http%3A%2F%2F(MY WEBSITE)%2Fimages%2F(IMAGENAME).png&cfs=1&upscale=1

Comment: I also tried deleting all images from the server and still I get the same image :/ 
What do I do ? :/

Comment: Using the debugger :
1. Object at URL 'http://(MY WEBSITE URL)/' of type 'designer' is invalid because the given value 'images/IMAGE.png' for property 'og:image:url' could not be parsed as type 'url'.

Comment: 2. To help you debug, these are the canonical URLs this URL used to point to : https://www.facebook.com/(MY FACEBOOK PAGE)

I used to forward my domain to my facebook page for long time. Now that I've made my website what should I do?

Comment: can you provide the url on which you are experiencing the error .

Comment: Its my website  and i cand provide it . That's  why I  posted all the necessary information  above.

Comment: I used to forward my domain to my facebook page before I make my website. That last 1-2 years. What do I do in this case?  Will my domain stay connected with the wrong images forever?

Comment: on debugger try clicking fetch new information . may be it will help . but can't say much without checking the url myself . check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27746216/open-graph-meta-tags-not-working-in-facebook/27754862#27754862

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason in my case was because there was a temporary cashing problem since my domain was linked to my facebook account for many years before linking it to an actual site. I had to wait for many days.