# Facebook - Meta tags (open graph)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

In an update of my previous question I received new warning from facebook debugger.

1. Parser Mismatched Metadata  The parser's result for this metadata did not match the input metadata. Likely, this was caused by the data being ordered in an unexpected way, multiple values being given for a property only expecting a single value, or property values for a given property being mismatched. Here are the input properties that were not seen in the parsed result: 'og:image:url, og:site_name, fb:admins'
2. og:image could not be downloaded or is too small    og:image was not defined, could not be downloaded or was not big enough. Please define a chosen image using the og:image metatag, and use an image that's at least 200x200px and is accessible from Facebook. Image Ηttp://(MY_WEBSITE)/images/mylogo.png will be used instead.
3. Attempted Frozen Title Change   It appears that you are trying to change the property og:title from (my_wesbite_name) to (my_wesbite_name_plus_tagline). If so, you are not allowed to for this object because too many actions have been published against it.

these are my tags:

```
    <meta property="og:title" content="Myname - Best Products in Town">
    <meta property="og:type" content="Product">
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.mybestproducts.com/">
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="Myname">
    <meta property="og:description" content="Selling the best products">
    <meta property="og:image" content="images/mylogo.png">
    <meta property="og:image:width" content="550">
    <meta property="og:image:height" content="550">
```

Questions:

About 1. I have no idea what that means

About 2: as seen in my meta tags I do have defined mylogo.png. Do I need to put the whole URL in order to recognize it.

About 3. I need an explenation for that one too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Meta tags for Open Graph - Facebook can't create thumbnail](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27770129/meta-tags-for-open-graph-facebook-cant-create-thumbnail)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concerning 1:

The `og:type` should be website in your case I guess, instead of product.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph

Concerning 2:

You need to pass an absolute path for the `og:image` property, instead of a relative one.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/creating-custom-stories/#objecttypes-properties

Concerning 3:

I think this is caused by the wrong `og:type`

Comment: If I add "designer" ? Is it wrong? I've seen people using it. How is this defined? Thanks for your time and your help :)

Comment: Don't know what you mean with *designer*. Refer to the docs I linked, and get the basics right...

Comment: Oh ok .. I didn't notice the link . Thanks :)